# gulp-ruby-sass not working with gulp-watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I am trying to watch scss files and only recompile them when they change. For ease of deployment, I want to use gulp-ruby-sass instead of gulp-sass.

I want to do this but the **task will hang on "dependency seen"**

```
// Doesn't work
var gulp = require('gulp')
var debug = require('gulp-debug')
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass')
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

watch("static/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(debug({title:'dependency seen'}))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(debug({title:'sassed'}))
```

The script works when I use vanilla gulp.src

```
// Works
var gulp = require('gulp')
var debug = require('gulp-debug')
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass')
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.src("static/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(debug({title:'dependency seen'}))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(debug({title:'sassed'}))
```

It also works when I use gulp-sass instead of gulp-ruby-sass

```
// Works
var gulp = require('gulp')
var debug = require('gulp-debug')
var sass = require('gulp-sass')
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

watch("static/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(debug({title:'dependency seen'}))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(debug({title:'sassed'}))
```

**This tells me that there is something wrong with the interaction between gulp-watch and gulp-ruby-sass.** Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found that gulp-ruby-sass-ns doesn't hang. The library doesn't seem quite as well supported however so I will leave this question open to see whether anyone else has any input

Answer (score 0):

Install [Gulp-Plumber](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-plumber) and call it right before you compile your sass.